# Jenkins multi-branch pipeline triggesr either for all branch that also fired as PRs or a specific branch

Tags: jenkins

I try to find a way to create a pipeline for all branches that also fired as PRs plus a specific branch, let's say a branch named 'develop' in Jenkins but no luck.

For now I need to create two jobs for it but I think it's better to merge them into only one.

Comment: Have you tried [Multibranch Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#creating-a-multibranch-pipeline)? Also I see no harm in using separate jobs (and local repositories) in this case. It can even improve performance if branches differ a lot.

Comment: Yes I am using Mutibranch Pipeline actually. I'm not sure if using separate jobs can improve perf. For example if we have many projects then each project might have 2 jobs so the branch indexing might consume resources. What do you think?

Comment: Let's assume you have 2 branches and they differ alot. Having only one local repository on jenkins machine would require restoring whole working tree again and again when new commits are pushed. Not to mention -> you can't run builds from different branches simultaneously using this approach.

Comment: Shouldn't it checkout the repo separately for each job in a temporary folder?

Comment: You are right @hxuanhung. Multibranch pipeline already performs checkout separately for each branch, so there would be no performance benefit I was talking about. Going back to the topic, what exactly can't you achieve using Multibranch pipeline?

Comment: I want one job to be triggered only in: either branches that also have open PRs or a given branch (for ex: develop). For now, I can create two jobs for each case  but I want to merge them into 1.

Comment: Where are you hosting your repository? On Github?

Comment: on Bitbucket. However I think the hosting is not important.

Comment: I've asked because apparently you need to install plugin on Jenkins that adds support for PR on Bitbucket/Github - [source](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#supporting-pull-requests). Unfortunately I cannot verify if it works, because I'm getting timeout exceptions while installing Bitbucket Branch Source plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your info. I had a look at the plugin and I think it only supports Bitbucket clounds and server